# OLE automation - WORD tabels (Delphi)

Tags: delphi, office-automation, ole-automation

I'm trying to make tables inside tables in WORD. of course in finall program it will be dinamical, which is not in this sample.

Here is my sample code.

```
 var
  aTable, bTable, cTable : OLEVariant;
begin
  m_WordApplication := CreateOleObject('Word.Application') ;
  m_WordDocument := m_WordApplication.Documents.Add;

  aTable := m_WordDocument.Tables.Add(m_WordApplication.Selection.Range, 2, 1);
  aTable.Borders.Item(wdBorderLeft).LineStyle:=wdLineStyleSingle;
  aTable.Borders.Item(wdBorderRight).LineStyle:=wdLineStyleSingle;
  aTable.Borders.Item(wdBorderTop).LineStyle:=wdLineStyleSingle;
  aTable.Borders.Item(wdBorderBottom).LineStyle:=wdLineStyleSingle;

  bTable := m_WordDocument.Tables.Add(aTable.Cell(1, 1).Range, 2, 1);
  bTable.Borders.Item(wdBorderLeft).LineStyle:=wdLineStyleSingle;
  bTable.Borders.Item(wdBorderRight).LineStyle:=wdLineStyleSingle;
  bTable.Borders.Item(wdBorderTop).LineStyle:=wdLineStyleSingle;
  bTable.Borders.Item(wdBorderBottom).LineStyle:=wdLineStyleSingle;

  cTable := m_WordDocument.Tables.Add(aTable.Cell(2, 1).Range, 3, 1);
  cTable.Borders.Item(wdBorderLeft).LineStyle:=wdLineStyleSingle;
  cTable.Borders.Item(wdBorderRight).LineStyle:=wdLineStyleSingle;
  cTable.Borders.Item(wdBorderTop).LineStyle:=wdLineStyleSingle;
  cTable.Borders.Item(wdBorderBottom).LineStyle:=wdLineStyleSingle;

  m_WordDocument.SaveAs('C:/test.doc', False) ;
  m_WordApplication.Quit(False);
```

Firstly i put new table(2 rows, 1 column) on position of the cursor, and then i try to put second table in cell(1,1) and third in cell(2,1) of the first table. second table has also 2 rows and 1 column, but third table has 3 rows and 1 column. but instead of what i want i get second and third table whit only one row, regardless if i putt something in thier cell or not.i always see only the last string i put in that table.

even more, if i put 1 row and 2 column table inside first table, than everything is normal.

can you help me.

thanks, Rok

Comment: Perhaps you can edit your post to make it more readable. (Most of all: proper spelling)

Comment: Also I strongly suggest to use early binding (= use the interfaces from the imported Word_TLB), which has a number of advantages over late binding like this (= using OleVariants)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have problems creating those tables in code, do the following:

- Open Word
- record a new macro
- While recording, build the table you want, then stop the recording.
- View your macro code in the Visual Basic Editor and try to translate that to OLE-automation code (which isn't that hard, it's almost the same)

Answer (score 0):

```
aTable.Borders.Item(wdBorderVertical).LineStyle:=wdLineStyleSingle;
aTable.Borders.Item(wdBorderHorizontal).LineStyle:=wdLineStyleSingle;
```

You will have to do the same for bTable & cTable.

When you add more than 1 row/column, it will need border to separate it (i.e to separate 1 row from another OR separate 1 column from another).

Hope this helps.